# React Native AnimationExperimental callback?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I've been playing around with react native and animations and would like to run animations in serial or chain animations together.  Is there a promise or a callback that fires when the animation is finished?  This is what I have so far:

```
AnimationExperimental.startAnimation({
    node: this.refs['this'],
    duration: 500,
    easing: 'easeInOutCubic',
    property: 'scaleXY',
    toValue: [2,2],
    callback: () => {  // This doesn't work but you get the idea.
        console.log("callback called!");
    }
});
```

### Update:

I found out that AnimationExperimental has been deprecated.  Facebook is working on a different animations library that should land soon.  You can also check out [react-native-gsap](https://github.com/skevy/react-native-gsap-demo) library if you can't wait for Facebook or is AminationExerimental doesn't work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback is the second parameter:

```
AnimationExperimental.startAnimation({
    node: this.refs['this'],
    duration: 500,
    easing: 'easeInOutCubic',
    property: 'scaleXY',
    toValue: [2,2]
}, () => {
        console.log("callback called!");
});
```